Does the loss function necessarily converge to zero as we get more samples?
Background: I'm reading quite a long paper(link) about quantile regression which uses the transfer learning method in this field. A crucial part of this method is to avoid negative transfer --when you have a new source dataset, you have to measure the 'distance' between the source data and the target data. If the two data are relatively ‘similar’, then the source data can be used to improve the estimation performance of the target statistical problem. Therefore, the authors provide a data-derived method to identify the transferable set and establish the consistency theory, which proved that we could choose the 'similar' source datasets correctly.
The proof procedure: In the proof on page 104, the authors show
$$
\begin{aligned}
& P\left(\varepsilon_0 L_0\left(\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_{\text {lasso }}, \mathcal{V}_{\text {te }}\right) \geq \min \left\{\frac{\kappa_0}{4}\left|\boldsymbol{\beta}_k^*-\boldsymbol{\beta}_0\right|_2^2, \frac{3 \kappa_0^3}{16 m_0}\left|\boldsymbol{\beta}_k^*-\boldsymbol{\beta}_0\right|_2\right\}\right. \\
& -c_3\left(\sqrt{\frac{s^{\prime} \log p}{n_k+n_0}}+\sqrt{h^{\prime}}\left(\frac{\log p}{n_k+n_0}\right)^{1 / 4}\right)\left|\boldsymbol{\beta}_k^*-\boldsymbol{\beta}_0\right|_2 \\
& -c_3\left(\sqrt{\frac{s^{\prime} \log p}{n_k+n_0}}+\sqrt{h^{\prime}}\left(\frac{\log p}{n_k+n_0}\right)^{1 / 4}+\sqrt{\frac{s_0 \log p}{n_0}}\right)^2 \\
& \left.-c_3 \sqrt{\frac{\log p}{n_0}}\left(s^{\prime} \sqrt{\frac{\log p}{n_k+n_0}}+h^{\prime}+s_0 \sqrt{\frac{\log p}{n_0}}+\left|\boldsymbol{\beta}_k^*-\boldsymbol{\beta}_0\right|_1\right)\right) \\
& +\frac{1}{p^2}+\frac{14+2 C_2}{p} 
\end{aligned}
$$
converge to zero. and under the condition
$$
\max \left\{\frac{s_0 \log p}{n_0}, s^{\prime} \sqrt{\frac{\log p}{n_0}} \sqrt{\frac{\log p}{n_k+n_0}}, h^{\prime} \sqrt{\frac{\log p}{n_0}}, \varepsilon_0\right\} \lesssim \min \left\{\frac{n_k^2 h^2}{\left(n_0^2+n_k^2\right)\left(s_0+s^{\prime}\right)}, \frac{n_k h}{\left(n_0+n_k\right) \sqrt{s_0+s^{\prime}}}\right\},
$$
(the RHS is about $|\beta_{k}^{\star}-\beta_0|_2 \ge \frac{2n_k\lambda h}{(n_0m_0 B^2 +2n_k \lambda)\sqrt{s_0+s\prime}}$, proved in lemma c.3 on page 99)
we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
& c_3\left(\sqrt{\frac{s^{\prime} \log p}{n_k+n_0}}+\sqrt{h^{\prime}}\left(\frac{\log p}{n_k+n_0}\right)^{1 / 4}\right)\left|\boldsymbol{\beta}_k^*-\boldsymbol{\beta}_0\right|_2 \\
& +c_3\left(\sqrt{\frac{s^{\prime} \log p}{n_k+n_0}}+\sqrt{h^{\prime}}\left(\frac{\log p}{n_k+n_0}\right)^{1 / 4}+\sqrt{\frac{s_0 \log p}{n_0}}\right)^2 \\
& +c_3 \sqrt{\frac{\log p}{n_0}}\left(s^{\prime} \sqrt{\frac{\log p}{n_k+n_0}}+h^{\prime}+s_0 \sqrt{\frac{\log p}{n_0}}+\left|\boldsymbol{\beta}_k^*-\boldsymbol{\beta}_0\right|_1\right)+\varepsilon_0 L_0\left(\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_{\text {lasso }}, \mathcal{V}_{\text {te }}\right) \\ 
&  \leq \min \left\{\frac{\kappa_0}{8}\left|\boldsymbol{\beta}_k^*-\boldsymbol{\beta}_0\right|_2^2, \frac{3 \kappa_0^3}{32 m_0}\left|\boldsymbol{\beta}_k^*-\boldsymbol{\beta}_0\right|_2\right\} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
when $n_k, n_0, p$ are sufficiently large. $L_0(\beta; \mathcal{A})= \frac{1}{|\mathcal{A}|}\sum \rho_{\tau}(Y_{0i}-Z_{0i}^{T}\beta)$ is the quantile loss function.(page22)
My question: This is how I understand the last part of the proof: each term in the LHS is quite small when $n_k$ goes to infinity. At the same time, the RHS also goes to zero but they are slightly larger than the LHS of the inequality under the stated condition.
I'm confused about the term $\varepsilon_0 L_0\left(\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_{\text {lasso }}, \mathcal{V}_{\text {te }}\right)$ where $\varepsilon_0$ has been bounded. From my previous understanding, $L_0$ has to be small enough and the term $\varepsilon_0 L_0\left(\widehat{\boldsymbol{\beta}}_{\text {lasso }}, \mathcal{V}_{\text {te }}\right)$ could be controled. Does $L_0$ go to zero as $n_k,n$ goes to infinity?
$|\beta_{k}^{\star}-\beta_0|_2$ measures the distance of the true parameters, Why not treat them as constants and let them change with $n_k,n$ instead?
It’s a long question, thanks in advance
